# Second derivative of $ \log \det ( X^{-1} +A) $ wrt $X$ where$ X $ is diagonal $A$ is positive definite.

Tags: matrices

I try to find the Hessian matrix of $\ln \det (diag(x)^{-1} +A)$, wrt $x$ in $\mathbb R^{n}_{++}$, with $A$ being positive definite. Could someone please help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mapsto \log(\det(U))\in\mathbb{R}$ where $U=A+diag(1/x_1,\cdots,1/x_n)$ is symmetric $>0$.

Then the derivative is the linear function

$Df_x:h\in\mathbb{R}^n\mapsto tr(U'(h)U^{-1})$ where $U'(h)=diag(\dfrac{-h_i}{x_i^2})$;

Then the hessian is the symmetric bilinear function

$D^2f_x:(h,k)\in(\mathbb{R}^n)^2\mapsto tr(U"(h,k)U^{-1}-U'(h)U^{-1}U'(k)U^{-1})$ where

$U"(h,k)=2diag(\dfrac{h_ik_i}{x_i^3})$.